# Pyinstaller Illegal Instruction 4 (other computers)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Running into a problem with pyinstaller. I'm trying to ship out an exe/app file using PyInstaller. However, anyone who tries to open my file ends up getting an Illegal Instruction 4 error.

This only happens when I try to compile on my machine and send to others. Others who compile using the same process and spec file do not see this same issue. When I open my own files, the exe and app files open without error.

Any and all ideas appreciated!

System Details:

OSX 10.9.4 (All machines are on this)

My PyInstaller output:

```
(veControl)ahaq-mbp-10028:asimov-control ahaque$ pyinstaller asimov_gui.spec --onefile
23 WARNING: You are running 64-bit Python: created binaries will only work on Mac OS X 10.6+.
If you need 10.4-10.5 compatibility, run Python as a 32-bit binary with this command:

VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes arch -i386 /Users/ahaque/asimov-control/veControl/bin/python

4029 INFO: UPX is not available.
4050 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
4152 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
4154 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
4220 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
4330 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
4424 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
4437 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
4756 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with /users/ahaque/asimov-control
4756 INFO: checking Analysis
4806 INFO: checking PYZ
4825 INFO: checking PKG
4844 INFO: checking EXE
4845 INFO: checking BUNDLE
4845 INFO: building BUNDLE out00-BUNDLE.toc
(veControl)ahaq-mbp-10028:asimov-control ahaque$
```

Output from others' terminal:

```
Last login: Mon Aug 11 13:05:00 on ttys002
LOADER: executable is /Users/dachelis/Downloads/Asimov_GUI 2
LOADER: homepath is /Users/dachelis/Downloads
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is /Users/dachelis/Downloads/Asimov_GUI 2
LOADER: Extracting binaries
LOADER: Executing self as child
LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to /var/folders/q6/nxdsj2_x6x3d32pcjqf2468wwtqnq6/T/_MEIlbLNev
LOADER: executable is /Users/dachelis/Downloads/Asimov_GUI 2
LOADER: homepath is /Users/dachelis/Downloads
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is /var/folders/q6/nxdsj2_x6x3d32pcjqf2468wwtqnq6/T/_MEIlbLNev
LOADER: archivename is /Users/dachelis/Downloads/Asimov_GUI 2
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: /var/folders/q6/nxdsj2_x6x3d32pcjqf2468wwtqnq6/T/_MEIlbLNev/.Python
LOADER: Manipulating evironment
LOADER: PYTHONPATH=/var/folders/q6/nxdsj2_x6x3d32pcjqf2468wwtqnq6/T/_MEIlbLNev
LOADER: PYTHONHOME=/var/folders/q6/nxdsj2_x6x3d32pcjqf2468wwtqnq6/T/_MEIlbLNev
LOADER: Manipulating Python's sys.path
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: extracted pyi_os_path
LOADER: extracted pyi_archive
LOADER: extracted pyi_importers
LOADER: Installing import hooks
LOADER: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running scripts
Illegal instruction: 4
logout

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also met problem like this, finally I switch to use [nuitka](http://nuitka.net/)  .

Answer (score 2):

This problem stems from an incompatibility of the version of python you are packaging.  You are likely using a version that you compiled on your system via Homebrew or MacPorts.  This likely resulted in a binary that is not fully compatible with other OS X machines because of compiler optimizations.  An easy solution is to download ActivePython and be sure that you are using it to package your source code.