# brewed python application bundled with py2app crashes with Illegal Instruction 4

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I want to build and deploy a hello world using a homebrewed `python` + `py2app`.

- Build machine: MacOS X 10.12.6
- Target machine: MacOS X 10.11

Following many posts I modified the `python.rb` formula by setting inside `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10` to insure backward compatibility with older macos kernels.

The build is OK but when I run the application on the target machine it crashes due to an **`Illegal Instruction 4`**. Digging a bit further, this crash is raised by calling the python bundled with the application.

Following that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251615/pyinstaller-illegal-instruction-4-other-computers) this might be due to the very nature of the homebrewed `python` that might be built with hardware specific optimization flags. Checking the output of my command

`brew install -v --build-from-source python`

I do not see any *exotic* flag but I can confirm that the deployment works when the application is built with a python that does not come from brew (e.g. from [www.python.org](http://www.python.org)).

Would you have any idea from where this problem comes from and how to modify the python brew recipe to make it work ?

Here are my codes:

**hello.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello world"
```

**build.py**

```
import sys
import os

from setuptools import setup

version = "1.0"
APP = ['hello.py']

PLIST = {
    u'CFBundleName': u'Hello',
    u'CFBundleShortVersionString': version,
    u'CFBundleVersion': version,
    u'CFBundleIdentifier': u'-',
    u'LSApplicationCategoryType': u'public.app-category.science'
}
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'plist': PLIST,
    'bdist_base': './Build/build',
    'dist_dir': './Build/dist',
    'graph': False,
    'xref': False
}

setup(
    name="hello",
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```